# Request with header {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;"} sends empty req.body

Tags: express, multipartform-data, rtk-query

I'm trying to save the formData below to MongoDB. In the payment below, "attachments" is a FileList.

What's happening is the response in the create controller returns an empty body when the header content type is multipart/form-data.
Otherwise, the create controller adds all the fields but not attachments. That returns an empty array.

What could I do on my controller so that I can create the payment with the attachment?

```js
const handlePaymentSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let payment = new FormData();
    payment.append("payee", user.id);
    payment.append("amount", paymentAmount);
    payment.append("code", paymentCode);
    payment.append("method", paymentMethod);
    payment.append("applicationId", applicationId);
    payment.append("attachments", attachments);
    await createPayment(payment);
    {
      isSuccess && dispatch(reset());
    }
  };
```

In createPayment RTK Endpoint I set the headers content-type to multipart form  data

```js
createPayment: builder.mutation({
      query: (payment) => ({
        url: "/api/payments/",
        method: "POST",
        body: payment,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;",
        },
      }),
```

On the backend,
I set how to store the files in middleware with Multer.

```js
import multer from "multer";

var storeImage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/payments");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let ext = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf("."));
    let name = file.originalname.substring(0, file.originalname.indexOf("."));
    cb(null, name + "-" + Date.now() + ext);
  },
});

export const storage = multer({
  storage: storeImage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (
      (file.mimetype =
        "image/png" || "image/jpg" || "image/jpeg" || "application/pdf")
    ) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      console.log("Only pdf, jpg and Png Supported");
      cb(null, false);
    }
  },
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2,
  },
});
```

And create the payment in my create controller.

```js
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import formidable from "formidable";
import Payment from "../../models/payment.js";

export const createPayment = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { payee, amount, code, method, applicationId } = await req.body;

  if (!payee || !amount || !code || !method || !applicationId) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Please add all required fields");
  }

  if (req.files) {
    let path = "";
    req.files.forEach(function (files, index, arr) {
      path = path + files.path + ",";
    });
    path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(","));
  }

  const attachments = req.files.map((attachment) => ({
    path: attachment.path,
    name: attachment.filename,
    size: `${(attachment.size / 1000).toFixed(2).toString()} KBs`,
  }));

  const payment = await Payment.create({
    payee,
    amount,
    code,
    method,
    applicationId,
    attachments,
  });

  res.status(200).json(payment);
});
```

Comment: remove semicolon from your  headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;",
        },

Comment: @BrijeshDave , thanks for spotting that. However, I still get an empty request body.

Comment: The `storage` you defined, are you sure you are using it as middleware somewhere?

Comment: please post your routes file and app.js file where you are configurung express app

Answer (score 4):

`"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;"` this won't work in rtk. By default, when you use RTK Mutation to send data, it will automatically serialize the data into a string format before sending it over the network. However, if you want to send form data without stringifying it, you can use the `formData` option.

Here's an example of how you can use the formData option in an RTK Mutation query:

```
createPayment: builder.mutation({
      query: (payment) => ({
        url: "/api/payments/",
        method: "POST",
        body: payment,
        formData: true
      }),
```

In this example, the `createPayment` mutation sends form data to the server without stringifying it. The formData option is set to true, which tells RTK Mutation not to serialize the data.

Note that when using the `formData` option, the `Content-Type` header will automatically be set to `multipart/form-data`, which is the standard format for sending form data.

Comment: Your answer is quite correct. It helped me resolve a similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: unable to get files on server, strange

Comment: i can get file in server but without contents,Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#49 // app/Http/Controllers/PostsController.php:29
  #parameters: []
}

Comment: This should work. Try consoling/printing the complete request and then try to debug